# Add custom tailwindcss class to Next.js-Tailwind project

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I have a Next.js-Tailwind project to which I want to add custom classes so that I can use them anywhere in the project.

I've tried a couple of things like this but doesn't seem to work.

tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    purge: [
        './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
        './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    ],
    darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
    theme: {
        extend: {
            height: {
                '60': '60rem',
                '40': '40rem',
                '55': '55rem',
                '180': '180px',
            },
            colors: {
                'primary': '#0B003A',
            },
        },
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/typography')],
}
```

What all do I need to do to use these classes globally across the project?

Comment: That seems to work for me. How are you using the custom classes in your code? Are they being applied to the elements in the DOM?

Comment: This settings works fine , confirmed ;-)